# Can only connect to my apache2/mysql/ssh server after I pinged the device im trying to connect from with the server itself

Tags: networking, ssh, apache2

I have Ubuntu running on an old laptop of mine, and I use it for my web development hobby. it's running an apache2 server, a mysql server and an ssh server. as the title says I can only connect to it after i ping whatever device I'm trying to connect from with my server. I suspect it could be a firewall issue, but I think I have configured my ufw correctly. Here is the config:

```
Status: active

22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I have no clue what it could be, so any help will be appreciated!